# Git делает объединение ветки master при отсутствии различий

Tags: git, github, git-merge

На хостинге лежит репозиторий git, делаем изменения на локальном компьютере, коммитим, но при команде `git pull` на сервере система осуществляет "слияние" ветки master с веткой master. Потом выдаёт ошибку что-то, что лежит на хостинге на 1 коммит впереди основного репозитория.

Делаю `git commit -m "server commit"` затем `git pull`. Ошибка уходит. В git клиенте появляется коммит с нулевыми изменениями

[image: -]

затем `Merge branch 'master'`. После всех этих перетрубаций, последующие коммиты проходят нормально, `git pull` просто подтягивает изменения, всё прекрасно обновляется.

Почему могут возникать такие ситуации? Почему он считает что файлы на хостинге отличны от тех что он тянет с сервера github ?

Comment: мне в голову приходит только одно - различные переносы строк. На сервере перед "странностями" файлы изменялись? (даже просто открыть в редакторе и нажать "сохранить") Или может файлы копировались на сервер в обход git'а?

Comment: "копировались на сервер в обход git'а" - вот это возможно было, мы действительно переезжали с сервера на сервер и как админ это переносил - непонятно, скорее всего просто копированием через SSH в обход git-а.

Comment: если возникает подобная ситуация, но Вы абсолютно уверенны, что ничего не менялось намеренно (или админ хитро скопировал), то нужно сделать следующее
git reset --hard origin/master

эта команда откатит текущий мастер на те коммиты, которые сейчас на origin (на github).

Answer (score 3):

Если `git` не мониторит изменения в файлах, то вероятнее всего изменились права доступа к файлам, не уверен что менеджер `git` с которым вы работаете показывает это в грамотной форме, обычно через `ssh` консоль очень четко видно изменения ли строк/прав доступа вы добавляете в коммит.

Answer (score 1):

В общем пользователь KoVadim правильно догадался что творилось с репозиториями и подсказал выход из положения. Репозитории действитльно переносились с сервера на серве в обход git т.е. тупо копированием через SSH между серверами, а не через **git clone** как того требует "фен шуй".

В результате репозиторий на сервере действительно отличался (наверное по переносам строк) от удалённого репозитория на github.com. Поэтому при попытке подтянуть изменения командой git pull система выдавала сообщение что файлы модифицированы со всеми вытекающими последствиями.

В результате выручила команда **git reset --hard origin/master**. Спасибо KoVadim! Выручил.

P.S. KoVadim не написал ответ на вопрос (написал всё в комментариях), поэтому чтобы закрыть вопрос, пишу развёрнутый ответ сам.

Comment: Скорее всего изменились права доступа, как Вам подсказывает @NikitaPimoshenko. Больше там нечему было изменится, при простом копировании.

Answer (score 0):

Почему вы уверены, что эти изменения - пустые? Если `git` говорит, что изменения есть - значит, они и правда есть.

Если проблема в переносах строк - может помочь правильная настройка `core.autocrlf` или настройка атрибутов в `.gitattributes`.

Если не помогает ничего - всегда можно откатить изменения с помощью `git reset`. Еще вариант - забрать изменения через `git fetch`, после чего сделать git checkout `origin/master -B master`. Это так же сбросит ветку на сервере до состояния из репозитория.

Comment: "Почему вы уверены, что эти изменения - пустые?" - я просто смотрю по git клиенту, он добавляет в коммит файлы, а напротив имени файла где обычно показано зелёная/красная шкала с цыфрами (сколько строк изменено) стоит серая шакала и ноль или вообще без цифр http://joxi.ru/ZrJV5lkSzLJarj.

Comment: Тогда используйте другой клиент, если у используемого вами такие баги, что файл изменен - а изменений ноль и их не посмотреть. Например, можно использовать консольный клиент - тем более что задача на сервере только забирать файлы из гита.

Comment: Могу даже написать нужную команду: `git fetch origin && git checkout origin/master` - ее для хостинга, где не вносится локальных изменений, будет достаточно всегда.